# Pandas: Filter rows by multiple occurrences of specific substrings in column cells

Tags: python, pandas, string, filter, count

Assuming the `dataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column_1': ['Apple', 'Apple Apple', 'Apple Apple', 'Peach Peach', 'Banana', 'Banana Banana'],
    'column_2': ['Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value']
})
```

which gives:

```
        column_1    column_2
0          Apple  Some value
1    Apple Apple  Some value
2    Apple Apple  Some value
3    Peach Peach  Some value
4         Banana  Some value
5  Banana Banana  Some value
```

How do I filter the rows (reassign the `df`) to only include rows where either the substrings `'Apple'` or `'Banana'` **occur more than once** in each string in each cell of `column_1`?

Note that I'd like to specify the filter to only look for multiple occurrences of `'Apple'` & `'Banana'` (not programmatically look for all multiple occurrences of any substring, e.g. `'Peach Peach'` should not be included).

I.e. the filtering should result in:

```
        column_1    column_2
1    Apple Apple  Some value
2    Apple Apple  Some value
5  Banana Banana  Some value
```

Comment: Do they need to occur consecutively, or do we also include: “my Banana is a Banana”? What about: “my Apple is first among Apples”? Or: “BananaBanana”? And does uppercase matter?

Comment: Do you want to do it specifically for `Apples` and `bananas`

Comment: @ouroboros1 Thanks for asking. All of the examples you listed can be included in the filter's resulting rows. So e.g. substrings can occur in any way within the cell string (non-consecutively) like "my Banana is a Banana". It should be case insensitive.

Comment: @Himanshuman Yes please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work for my purposes (thanks to @Himanshuman for pointing in this direction):

```
import re

df = df[
        (df['column_1'].str.count(r'apple', re.I) > 1) | \
        (df['column_1'].str.count(r'banana', re.I) > 1)
        ]
```

It uses the bitwise OR operator (`|`) between the conditions [with `\` as line break character]
and will give the desired result):

```
                             column_1    column_2
1                         Apple Apple  Some value
2                         Apple Apple  Some value
5                       Banana Banana  Some value
6                      Apple is Apple  Some value
7  Banana is not Apple but is Banana   Some value
```

Answer (score 3):

Check Below answer (kept column Apple_Banana_count for sanity check):

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column_1': ['Apple', 'Apple Apple', 'Apple Apple', 'Peach Peach', 'Banana', 'Banana Banana'],
    'column_2': ['Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value']
})

df.assign(Apple_Banana_count =  df['column_1'].apply(lambda x: len([m.start() for m in re.finditer('Apple|Banana', x)]))).\
query('Apple_Banana_count > 1')
```

Output:

[image]

Updated code as per the Op's comment - Leaving unfiltered for Sense Check (You can filter on these columns to get the required result):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column_1': ['Apple', 'Apple Apple', 'Apple Apple', 'Peach Peach', 'Banana', 'Banana Banana', 'Apple Banana','Banana blash blah Apple '],
    'column_2': ['Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value']
})

df.assign(Apple_Banana_count =  df['column_1'].apply(lambda x: len([m.start() for m in re.finditer('Apple|Banana', x)])),
Apple_and_Banana=  df['column_1'].apply(lambda x: len([m.start() for m in re.finditer('(?=.*Apple)(?=.*Banana)', x)]))
)
```

OutPut:

[image]

Comment: This mostly works (for me), so thank you. But one caveat as @ouroboros1 mentioned in another comment is that it will erroneously include `'Apple Banana'`. So ideally it should avoid this.

Comment: Check updated code - You can filter on these columns to get required result

Comment: Thanks, I suppose `df.query('Apple_Banana_count > 1 & Apple_and_Banana == 0')` may work as a filter.

Comment: Yeah it will just checked

Answer (score 3):

If the string to match is only `Apple and Bananas` you can use regex with [`pandas.Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html).

```
df[df['column_1'].str.count('Apple|Banana') > 1]
```

This gives us the expected output

```
        column_1    column_2
1    Apple Apple  Some value
2    Apple Apple  Some value
5  Banana Banana  Some value
```

**EDIT:**
As @ouroboros1, suggested the above won't work in case OP has `Apple Banana` in the row.

Here is the case where I have tried to cover such cases.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column_1': ['Apple Banana','Apple', 'Apple Apple', 'Apple Apple', 'Peach Peach', 'Banana', 'Banana Banana', 'Apple Banana Apple'],
    'column_2': ['Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value', 'Some value']
})
```

```
             column_1    column_2
0        Apple Banana  Some value
1               Apple  Some value
2         Apple Apple  Some value
3         Apple Apple  Some value
4         Peach Peach  Some value
5              Banana  Some value
6       Banana Banana  Some value
7  Apple Banana Apple  Some value
```

We can use `extractall`  to get our pattern group in multiple columns then we apply count to get all `not nan` values count then we use reindex to get the dataframe containing false value for those rows that did not have a match and filled those value with False. We then select only those values containing atleast one `True` value. Then we filter our original dataframe with `True` values in the index.

```
df[(df['column_1'].str.extractall('(Apple)|(Banana)').groupby(level=0).agg('count')>1).reindex(df.index, fill_value=False).any(axis=1)]
```

This gives is the expected output

```
             column_1    column_2
2         Apple Apple  Some value
3         Apple Apple  Some value
6       Banana Banana  Some value
7  Apple Banana Apple  Some value
```

Comment: Doesn't meet the requirements specified in the comments. Also, it would capture `Apple Banana`, which it shouldn't.

Comment: @ouroboros1 check my updated answer

Comment: Seems to do the job! Good redraft

Comment: @Himanshuman How do you think this compares to the [solution I proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73223734/4909923)? I might be missing something that is handled better by your code.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the rows where 'Apple' or occurs more than once amounts to keeping the rows with at least 2 times 'Apple' and therefore containing 'Apple Apple'. This can be done with

```
words_to_keep = 'Apple', 'Banana'
words_to_keep = [' '.join([word] * 2) for word in words_to_keep]
# repeat the words 2 times
df = df.loc[df['column_1'].str.contains('|'.join(words_to_keep))]
# keep only the rows containing the repeated words using regex
```